# How to upper-bound $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{s_i}{i + \sqrt{s_i}}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{s_i}{i + {s_i}}$?

Tags: inequality, convergence-divergence, time-series

Any ideas how to upper bound $A$, $B$, $C$ and/or $D$:

$$
B = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{s_i}{i + {s_i}}
$$

$$
C = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i + \sqrt{s_i}}
$$

$$
D = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i + {s_i}}
$$

as a function of $S = \sum_{i=1}^n s_i$, $P = \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{s_i}$ and/or $\sum_{i=1}^n 1/i = O(\log n)$ (and possibly some other things)?

Update: The assumption is that $s_i \geq 1, \forall i$.

Comment: Any restrictions on the $s_i$?

Comment: Nothing. We just know their sum (or some other statistics).

Comment: It's not true that $\log n=\sum 1/i$.

Comment: @Wojowu approximately ?

Comment: changed it to big-Oh notation.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to assume the $s_i$ are non-negative? Indeed, $P$ assumes this, no?

Comment: Ah yeah. They are all above 1. I will update it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out @MatthewConroy.